# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ['0.016487999999999999']

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, string-conversion

I am trying to read the file that contains string-numbers, but it gives me error when I try to convert string-numbers to float. I know this may be because of large size of numbers, but is there any alternative way to convert string numbers to float? I have looked to existing solutions but I did not find any relevant.

```
def load_embeddings(self, FileName = \
                'Resources/EN-wform.w.5.cbow.neg10.400.subsmpl.txt'):

        file = open(FileName,'r')

        for line in file:
            tokens = line.split('\t')

            #since each line's last token content '\n'
            # we need to remove that
            tokens[-1] = str(tokens[-1].split())

            #each line has 400 tokens
            for i in xrange(1, len(tokens)):
                # pass
                print "token ", tokens[i]
                print type(tokens[i])
                print float(tokens[i])
```

Output with Error:

```
token  0.017045999999999999
<type 'str'>
0.017046
token  0.038705999999999997
<type 'str'>
0.038706
token  0.033797000000000001
<type 'str'>
0.033797
token  ['0.016487999999999999']
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "featureExtraction.py", line 51, in <module>
    f.load_embeddings()
  File "featureExtraction.py", line 38, in load_embeddings
    print float(tokens[i])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ['0.016487999999999999']
```

Comment: Your file has `[]` around one of the numbers.

Comment: You can replace `str(tokens[-1].split())` with `tokens[-1].strip()`

Comment: BTW: the closest [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) to 0.016487999999999999 is 0.01648800075054168701171875

Comment: thanks @Barmar i found that.